# Cocoa memory management, why does my app keep using more?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, memory-management

I made a xfire client for mac (called BlackFire -> http://www.macxfire.com)
and it keeps using more and more ram over time, even when not doing that much.

I have run the app with instruments::leaks and it doesn't show any leaks at all (when it did i fixed them quickly).
Somehow it still keeps using more ram, like it is supposed to or something idk.
I have minimized the use of autoreleased objects and I have checked for any leaks using build & analyze with no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get yourself back to Instruments and use Object Alloc to see what objects / allocations are increasing over time.

More likely than not, you have a cache or a log or the like that is simply growing over time... is never being truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Try building it with Garbage Collection enabled and see if it does the same thing.

If not, then you know you still have some leaks to find.  If it does, time to look at caches/logs/etc and find out what's eating memory.

Comment: Garbage collection is not an option, it would make the app unneccesary slow and unstable + it won't work :) Leaks would find leaks if I would have objects allocated but the pointer to it set to nil wich the garbage collector would "collect"

Comment: GC does not incur the overhead you describe in most cases, but -- yes -- it probably isn't appropriate for this project given the reliance upon a large third party library.